# What is the meaning of 'an expression of such smugness that Harry thought it ought to be fined'?

Tags: meaning, verbs

> Harry took the hint and sat down next to Percy, who was wearing brand-new, navy-blue dress robes and **an expression of such smugness that Harry thought it ought to be fined**. (Harry Potter 4 [US Version]: p.415)[Bold font is mine]

I thought at first ‘fine’ in this sentence meant ‘to make somebody pay money as an official punishment’. However, I’m starting to doubt my first judge; I couldn’t find any examples of the ‘fine’ which accepts blamable things, like smugness, as its direct object.

Would you give me the true meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; the idea J.K. Rowling is expressing here is that Percy ought to be fined for having the expression, not that the expression itself ought to be fined.

Answer (score 1):

It means Percy should pay money as a punishment for being too smug.

Comment: @totoro, However not literally, but figuratively; see simile.